# Android Studio stays in offline mode

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Android newby here. For some reason Gradle keeps running in offline mode which keeprs my app from running.

I've tried the following:

1. View -> Tools Window -> Gradle -> toggle offline mode off
2. Add "startParameter.offline=false" inside settings.gradle
3. Remove all traces of Android Studio and reinstalled the app

I'm running on Red Hat (latest version)

Best regards,

Lucas

Answer (score 0):

So apperantly a failty dependency was to blame. I was using

```
implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-jackson:<latest-version>'
```

Which for some reason caused the offline error (it dit build when i pushed the "disable Gradle offline mode and sync project"). I completely removed the line because I'm not using the library any way.